# Who were the Canaanites?

Tags: exodus, canaan

Why did God send his angel of death in Exodus 23:23 to kill people that already lived on the chosen land for the chosen ones?

> Ex 23:23 (ESV) - “When my angel goes before you and brings you to the
> Amorites and the Hittites and the Perizzites and the Canaanites, the
> Hivites and the Jebusites, and I blot them out

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here which I will address separately.

1. **Who were the Canaanites?**

The simplistic answer to this question is that the Canaanites were the descendants of Canaan.  His position in history is given in Gen 10:1, 6, 15-19

> This is the account of Noah’s sons Shem, Ham, and Japheth, who also
> had sons after the flood. ...
>
> The sons of Ham: Cush, Mizraim, Put, and **Canaan**. ...
>
> And Canaan was the father of Sidon [= Sidonians] his firstborn, and of
> the Hittites, the Jebusites, the Amorites, the Girgashites, the
> Hivites, the Arkites, the Sinites, the Arvadites, the Zemarites, and
> the Hamathites. Later the Canaanite clans were scattered, 19and the
> borders of Canaan extended from Sidon toward Gerar as far as Gaza, and
> then toward Sodom, Gomorrah, Admah, and Zeboiim, as far as Lasha.

2. **Why were the Canaanites Eliminated?**

This is far more contentious and difficult to answer; ie, extremely controversial.  The simplistic answer is that is what God's sovereign will decided.

The more detailed answer involves what God said in Jer 18:7-10 -

> If at any time I announce that a nation or kingdom is to be uprooted,
> torn down and destroyed, and if that nation I warned repents of its
> evil, then I will relent and not inflict on it the disaster I had
> planned. And if at another time I announce that a nation or kingdom is
> to be built up and planted, and if it does evil in my sight and does
> not obey me, then I will reconsider the good I had intended to do for
> it.

Thus, God decided to eliminate the Canaanites for the same reason he destroyed the Sodomites as recorded in Gen 18, 19 - they had become so wicked that God could no longer reach them.  [Consider how wicked the Sodomites had become - they would welcome visitors to the city be pack raping them.  A modern equivalent might be mercifully short-lived ISIS/ISIL/Daesh which trained their children to hate anyone opposed to them by beheadings!]

One presumes that the Canaanites had reached this advanced state of depravity and shut themselves out from the promptings of the Holy Spirit (cf. Ps 51:10, 11).

God had actually predicted this, hundreds of years earlier in Gen 15:16 when speaking to Abraham -

> In the fourth generation your descendants will return here, for the
> iniquity of the Amorites is not yet complete.

Answer (score 0):

**Cycle of Nations** Historians have noted a cyclical history of nations throughout time. They begin (1) with a Cause or call for justice, (2) instigate a revolt or revolution, (3) establish a new government, (4) enjoy economic growth, (4) become lax and libertarian through prosperity, (5) increase in wicked life styles, and (6) arrive at the need for judgment. (See histories by Toynbee, H.G. Wells, etc.)

The **Providential Judgment** is brought on by God (using the instrument of another warlike nation) because to leave the nation unchecked would pollute all nations around them, and would cause an earthly situation/dilemma that existed just before the Flood of Noah's era.(Genesis; *Every thought of the imagination of the heart was wicked*...)

**Rampant Diseases** Note that in ancient days there were no antibiotics or other medicines to stop the plagues and diseases associated with sin (especially VDs). So if the Israelites moved in *with the Canaanites* they would have been affected with the diseases also. Thus the seeming genocide was necessary to preserve a new civilization...the old one having gone past the line of repentance (dead conscience; Genesis 15:16). God told the Israelites that *if you obey me, none of the diseases of the Egyptians would come upon them!* as well.

**Angel of Death** It should be noted the *the Angel of Death* could in God's Providence be (1) an instigator of a plague (as in David's day), or (2) a confusing of soldier's in an armed force (as in the Israelite battles), or (3) the arousing of a foreign army to invade (See, *I will drive out them by hornets* in reference to the Egyptian "hornet kings" whose invasions weakened the Canaanites so Joshua could easily conquer them!)

**Canaanite Tribes** The "Land of the Canaanites" refers to the area between Syria on the north and Egypt on the south, in the Mideast, wherein lived many small tribes that were idolatrous, heathen people groups: Jebusite, Amorites, Girgashites, Arvadites, *et al.*. Their society was rife with wickedness, worshipping gods that involved even killing babies as a sacrificial ritual. Their conduct, by the time 400 years had transpired after Abraham, was vile, just as God had predicted. (Genesis 15:16; See books on Biblical Archaeology, as well as Historical Geography, and Commentaries on Genesis.)

**Contemporary note**: Where do some modern nations lie on the continuum of national cycling? Has societal conduct such as habitual drug use, rampant fornication, corporate greed, prolicide, euthanasia, godlessness, philosophical or practical atheism, divorce rates, unchecked lawlessness...made them "ripe for destruction"?  Does God have punishing armies "waiting in the wings" just ready for the command being given to **the angel of death**?